Matlab editor doesn't fill window
(EDIT: I submitted a bug report to Mathworks and it turns out this is a known bug which will be fixed in a future release. A workaround is to go to the system settings and change the display resolution to 100%; previously it was 125% or something. My original question follows.)
I am working with Matlab R2024a on Windows 10.
I have opened a separate editor window. I find that the editor only uses about two thirds of the available space; there is a large empty area to the right and a large empty area below the part of the window actually occupied by the editor. It appears that the editor is allowing for GUI elements which are not present; I'm guessing the workspace browser to the right and the command console below. However, those elements are not in the editor window.
How can I convince the editor to occupy the entire window?
The problem is illustrated by this screenshot:


I presume you've already tried the standard trouble-shooting practices of restarting MATLAB, restarting the computer, etc. Are you working with multiple displays of different resolutions? I've had issues when I open MATLAB on my laptop, then connect to an external monitor and move the window there.

This looks like an issue to reach out to MathWorks directly on. Consider filing a ticket.
